# degree of a self map on the sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

could you help me with this one? How do I determine the degree of the continous map $\mathbb{S}^n\to \mathbb{S}^n$ induced by multiplication with an orthogonal matrix $A$? I think it should be $\det(A)$.

I would appreciate your answers!

Comment: There are lots of definitions of the degree and the proofs that they're equivalent are nontrivial. Which one are you working with?

Comment: For a continous self map f on $\mathbb{S}^n$ look at the induced homomorphism $\tilde{H}_n (f):\tilde{H}_n(\mathbb{S}^n)\to(\mathbb{S}^n).$ The degree is then given by $\tilde{H}_n(f)\mu_n=\deg(f)\mu_n$ for $\mu_n$ the fundamental class in $\tilde{H}_n(\mathbb{S}^n)$.

Answer (score 1):

If the determinant of the matrix is $1$, then the mapping is homotopic to the identity. If the determinant is $-1$, then the mapping is homotopic to a reflection. This follows from the fact the set of orthogonal matrices with determinant $1$ (resp. $-1$) is path connected. The degree of the identity and a reflection are well known.